# How can I set height for Twitter bootstrap thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I’m having trouble setting up the Thumbnail module for my personal website. I use twitter bootstrap (3.0) for my project and I can’t finish setting up the Thumbnail module.

The width is okay, but I can’t set the height of thumbnails (I can’t align all thumbnails as the same height).

**How I can set one (standard) height for all the thumbnails and zoom/scale image to center so they can fill all space without stretching the image?**

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Thumbnail 0 -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img.png" alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
        <h4>Arctic MX-2, 8g</h4>
    </div>
</div><!-- /thumbnail 0 -->
<!-- Thumbnail 1 -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="blue.png" alt="...">
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
        <h4>Arctic MX-2, 8g</h4>
    </div>
</div><!-- /thumbnail 1 -->
</div><!-- /thumbnail -->
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

either in css:

```
.thumbnail img { min-height:50px; height:50px; } // or whatever height you desire
```

or inline:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="..." style="min-height:50px;height:50px;" />
```

Comment: `.thumbnail img { min-height: 200px; }` Ok, now is partially working... I need to crop the picture up to 200px in order to have it done. Also the last image is stretched. [Result](http://i.imgur.com/fLy0t3c.png)

Comment: if your thumbnails are not all the same aspect ratio, then you have two options - either you can use css to make the images fit a pre-determined height and width - which will cause some images to be skewed, or you set a fixed height _or_ width, which will preserve the original aspect ratio of the thumbnail, but may cause problems in the overal layout.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379318/have-thumbnails-with-different-images-sizes-bootstrap) to change thumbnail and image size, hope helps

Answer (score 8):

Hey I was looking at your question, cause I have had the same problem in Bootstrap where if one of the `<div>`'s height is higher than the other's, then the grid doesn't display properly. I figured out how to fix the thumbnail align problem, and I think many people could be using the CSS Flex property.

In the div `class="row"` I added `style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;"`. Basically, my code looks like this:

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300" style="width:200px">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Some thumbnail heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300" style="width:200px">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Some thumbnail heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  .. any number of thumbnails you want
</div>
```

So you can have different thumbnail heights and it will display properly, maybe not as [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but at least better.

Answer (score 2):

With SCSS, you can simply:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {.thumbnail img { height:100px; }}
@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {.thumbnail img { height:150px; }}
@media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {.thumbnail img { height:200px; }}
```