# Have Thumbnails with different images sizes Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I will like to have thumbnail with images of different sizes and different amount of text. But I want them to all have the same size. Like this [example from the Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content).

Below is the code I have at the moment, with a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/fW22a/2/embedded/result/).

I have different images size, so this gets broken. Is this possible with Bootstrap?

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h3>
            Fading a RGB LED on BeagleBone Black
        </h3><img src="https://learn.adafruit.com/system/guides/images/000/000/322/medium310/overview_web.jpg?" alt="Sample Image">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>In this tutorial, you will learn how to control the color of an RGB LED using a BeagleBone Black and Python.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <h3>
            Measuring Light with a BeagleBone Black
        </h3><img src="https://learn.adafruit.com/system/guides/images/000/000/316/medium310/overview_web.jpg?" alt="Sample Image">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>In this tutorial, you will learn how to connect a photoresistor to a BeagleBone Black. The tutorial can also be used for other resistive sensors such as FSRs or SoftPots.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining dimensions for your containers.

for example in your container element(.thumbnail), set a specific dimensions to follow like:

```
.thumbnail{        
    width: 300px; 
    // or you could use percentage values for responsive layout
    // width : 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.thumbnail img{
    // your styles for the image
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

and so on with the other elements.

**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fW22a/3/embedded/result/)**

Comment: This won't work with responsive `col-xx-y` but it is a good idea. I'd even say `overflow: hidden`

Comment: That doesn't work if the content within each thumbnail changes. For example, if the paragraph triples in size, it will expand past the set height/width. I don't know a better solution though. Probably same logic as, "Masonry Gallery". But, again don't know how to do this in JQuery or any other code. I would love a good solve on this!!

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with CSS on the `img` tag.

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

or inline on each `img` tag like this

```
<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px" src="https://learn.adafruit.com/system/guides/images/000/000/339/medium310/overview_web.jpg" alt="Sample Image">
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should setup height of those columns. In example we have same amount of text, so it has same height for each div.

Comment: How exactly I do that, if I'm using bootstrap. Not quite sure :(

Comment: add css rule `.image-holder { height: 500px; }` and add one more class to div `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 image-holder">`

Comment: what about if I want to add a css rule to the img to have a max-width. I have this, but it doesn't works: img {max-width: 50%;}

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, hope it help!

```
  <style type="text/css">
  .row{
    display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .row>[class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"]{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This is great solution without giving any fixed value.